# what is the difference between expected and actual values in Assert.Matches()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, assert

The static Matches is

```
public static void Matches(string expectedRegexPattern, string actualString);
```

What is the difference between when I pass `expectedRegexPattern` value instead of `actualString` value and passing `actualString` value instead of `expectedRegexPattern` value?

**Way 1 -** `Assert.Matches("EN", result[0].LanguageCode);`

**Way 2 -** `Assert.Matches(result[0].LanguageCode,"EN");`

> Both of ways doing same work with same performance. So am confused about the difference between the above ways and which one is best?

Comment: Of course both return the same, as `x == y` ==> `y == x`. However the question is just: which is your *expected* behaviour, and what do you *actually get*. That´s what the two parameters stand for.

Comment: The first parameter is what you **expect**. The second is what your unit test **actually got**. Take `Assert.AreEqual` for example. Compare what happens when you run `Assert.AreEqual(4,2)` vs `Assert.AreEqual(2,4)`. The message returned is different.

Comment: Voting to close as "what is best" completely depends on what you want to test, which is quite opinion-based.

Comment: also I would suspect that the first is a regular expression pattern (to be matched, like `"EN|DE"`), while the second is just the string to match that pattern. And would be interesting to see what happens when the values are not equal...

Comment: I'm voting to reopen as the parameter order is _not_ opinion-based in this context, and to some extent to assertion calls in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Stivi correctly points out a significant difference in the case of `Matches`, but there's another less significant but still important distinction even for `Equals` and other assertion methods.

You might get an incorrect message in the test log output. Many testing frameworks will log an error such as

> Values do not match: expected: {expectedValue}, actual: {actualValue}".

So if you switched them, you'd see the wrong "expected" value, potentially confusing someone trying to diagnose a problem.

Take this test as an example:

```
void TestValueIsZero():
{
    int value = 1;
    Assert.Equals(0, value);
    // logs "Values to not match. expected: 0, actual: 1
    Assert.Equals(value, 0);
    // logs "Values to not match. expected: 1, actual: 0
}
```

Someone looking at the failed test logs might be confused by the incorrect "expected" and "actual" values in the log due to the switched parameters.

The *mechanics* may be exactly the same regardless of the order of parameters (compare the two objects and return true if no differences are found), but the *semantics* are still important.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that you are using xunit as test framework because i have found that method there. So if you only want to check if both strings have the same content you could also use `Assert.Equal("Your text", "Your text")`. The `Assert.Matches` method is used to validate if your text is in a desired format. The format is described by .net regular expressions. For example with this call `Assert.Matches("^[0-9]$", "1")` you can check if your string is a number between 0 and 9. If you change the order of the parameters to `Assert.Matches( "1", "^[0-9]$")` the method will throw an exception and your test will be marked as failed.

Comment: Everything is okay.. But '0-9' syntax is right??

Comment: Okay.. I'll give you for the first up vote... Welcome to stack overflow

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah you are right there was a an error. I did correct it. As a hint I recommend to use the FluentAssertions nuget package to increase the readability of tests. With that package you can write 'stringToCheck.Should().Be("value")' instead of 'Assert.Equal("value", stringToCheck)'